# Как читать логи приложения на андроид?

Tags: android, java, логирование

Как читать логи приложения на андроид?  как вы в них что то понимаете? 
например это:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.vk.liker.PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.my.app.PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1790)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)
at com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.my.app.PlaceholderFragment; no empty constructor
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Смотри где написано `Caused by`: там все написано)

> Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.my.app.PlaceholderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

и

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.my.app.PlaceholderFragment; no empty constructor

Comment: это ошибка, да. а строку, которая вызвала ошибку, надо искать по имени своего пакета, класса (начиная сверху). Т.е. 

> at com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)

в 80 строке MainActivity произошел вызов, приведший к падению.

Comment: а как в эклипсе узнать строку?